# I am trying to implement a Login and Logout functionality

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement a Login and Logout functionality.
Everything is working fine, but login in after showing home screen it's showing not show the logout button but after the app opens and closes shows the logout button.

```
   const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
   useEffect(() => {
        getTokenData()

    }, [])

    const getTokenData = async () => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');
        setIsToken(token)
        console.warn(token)
        if (token !== null) {
            setIsLoggedIn(true)
            console.warn('logout true')
        }
        else {
            console.warn('logout Success')
        }
    };

    const handleSignIn = () => {
       
        setIsLoggedIn(false)
        console.warn('sign in')
        navigation.navigate('SignIn')
    }
    const handleLogout = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('access_token')
        setIsLoggedIn(false)
        console.warn('logout')
        navigation.navigate('HomePage')
    }

  {isLoggedIn ?
   <Btn btnLabel={'Logout'} onPress={handleLogout} />:
   <Btn btnLabel={'Sign In'} onPress={handleSignIn} /> 
 }
```

Comment: did you try adding `setIsLoggedIn(true)` at the end of `handleSignIn( )`?

Comment: can you update your question writing which page does the code you wrote belongs to? It's also unclear which flow the logout button is not being rendered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70622599/useeffect-is-not-called-when-navigating-back-to-screen-react-navigation

Answer (score 0):

I have answered similar question in this link. [Auth Workflow - Persistent Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76077773/auth-workflow-persistent-login)

If you are using axios , redux it will be helpful for you.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        if (isFocused) {
            getTokenData();
        }
        // console.warn("islofgin chages")
    }, [isLoggedIn, isFocused])